# more then one jquery calculate on same page

Tags: jquery

I need some help running two jquery.calculation on the same page, in my example only the 2nd table is working, I have added the script 2x and have renamed all the elements but it's not working.

When I remove the 2nd script the 1st one is working.
When I add the 2nd script the first one stops.

I understand that somehow these 2 scripts need to be combine but I really do not know how.

Thank you.

Here is an example:
[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/Z2zyz/)

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#idPluginVersion").text($.Calculation.version);
        $("[name^=qty_]").bind("change keyup", recalc);
        $("[name^=aantal_]").bind("change keyup", recalc);
        $("[name^=price_]").bind("change keyup", recalc);
        $("[name^=bedrag_]").bind("change keyup", recalc);
        recalc();
    });

    function recalc() {
        $("[id^=total_item]").calc(
            "((qty * price) + (aantal * bedrag))", {
            qty: $("[name^=qty_]"),
            aantal: $("[name^=aantal_]"),
            price: $("[id^=price_]"),
            bedrag: $("[id^=bedrag_]")
        },

        function(s) {
            return s.toFixed(2);
        },

        function($this) {
            var sum = $this.sum();
            $("#subTotal").val(sum.toFixed(2));
        });
    }
</script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#idPluginVersion").text($.Calculation.version);
        $("[name^=qty2_]").bind("change keyup", recalc);
        $("[name^=aantal2_]").bind("change keyup", recalc);
        $("[name^=price2_]").bind("change keyup", recalc);
        $("[name^=bedrag2_]").bind("change keyup", recalc);
        recalc();
    });

    function recalc() {
        $("[id^=total2_item]").calc(
            "((qty2 * price2) + (aantal2 * bedrag2))", {
            qty2: $("[name^=qty2_]"),
            aantal2: $("[name^=aantal2_]"),
            price2: $("[id^=price2_]"),
            bedrag2: $("[id^=bedrag2_]")
        },

        function(s) {
            return s.toFixed(2);
        },

        function($this) {
            var sum = $this.sum();
            $("#subTotal2").val(sum.toFixed(2));
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: You have the `$(document).ready()` and `function recalc()` twice, so one is overwriting the other.

Comment: You also have a large number of "valid HTML" issues you need to address. When you put code in JSFiddle, stick the scripts in the lower window and press the tidyup button... All the little red indications in the HTML are problems you need to fix :) Half you input do not have closing "/" and you actually have class="hide" on closing tags!!!!

Comment: When you want to "duplicate" functionality you don't go and copy the code twice, you adapt it to handle multiple elements

Comment: You would not need to duplicate the JQuery code at all if you change the selectors to act only on the "closest table" to the source of each recalc() event call. To do that though, you have to stop using IDs and use class names instead so that duplicates can occur in each table. Pass `this` to each recalc() call and let it find the parent table using `$(this).closest('table')`

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Now that I got some free time, I have modified this for you so that it is much simpler and more efficient code. It also seems to work fine in the JSFiddle I made. Note: I am pasting the total JQuery/JS code in here, but I added several classes in your HTML to make it work. You can look into that in the JSFiddle. To make them easier to find, they were added to the "qty", "aantal", "price", "bedrag", "total_item" and "subTotal" inputs. Finally, I added into all the `onclick` functions you had to pass `this` in as a paramter, like this: `onclick="recalc(this)"`.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Z2zyz/7/)

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#idPluginVersion").text($.Calculation.version);
        $(".qty").bind("change keyup", function(event) {
            recalc($(this));
        });
    });

    function recalc(curr) {
        var close = $(curr).closest("table");

        $(close).find(".total_item").calc(
            "((qty * price) + (aantal * bedrag))", {
            qty: $(close).find(".qty"),
            aantal: $(close).find(".aantal"),
            price: $(close).find(".price"),
            bedrag: $(close).find(".bedrag")
        },

        function(s) {
            return s.toFixed(2);
        },

        function($this) {
            var sum = $this.sum();
            $(close).find(".subTotal").val(sum.toFixed(2));
        });
    }
</script>
```

EDIT: To get "0.00" in your subTotal fields by default, just add it as a value to those 2 inputs like this:

```
<input id="subTotal" class="subTotal" style="text-align:right;" type="text" name="SubTotal" readonly="readonly" size="7" value="0.00" />

<input id="subTotal2" class="subTotal" style="text-align:right;" type="text" name="SubTotal2" readonly="readonly" size="7" value="0.00" />
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Z2zyz/9/)

Comment: Encouraging a mess of duplication does not really help make it right. Pass `this` to a single recalc and use $(this).closest('table') to limit the JQuery selector searches.

Comment: I agree, but he asked for help with his code, so that's what I did. Refactoring is a completely different ballgame.

Comment: Might as well toss a grenade in after it :)

Comment: No problem, but please do note what others suggested and consider refactoring this. You could eliminate your duplicated function with some refactoring.

Comment: I'm totally new at this, did I do something else wrong? I'm not sure what "refactoring" means, I'm from the Netherlands so english is not my native language, I'm not used to coding.

Comment: It basically means to make your code simpler and more efficient. In your case: why do something twice when you can handle it in one function.

Comment: I got some free time and made this more efficient as others had suggested. If you want, you can use it to give yourself some cleaner code to work with.

Comment: +1: now that deserves upvoting. Fixes the problem in a fraction of the code with no repeating. *(I took the liberty of pressing TidyUp on the JSFiddle and formatting your code)*

Comment: Thank you all so much for this amazing help, looking at the code I also learned a bit more about it.

I wish I could +100 you all but since I'm new here I don't seem to have enough reputation.

Once again, Thank you. <3

Comment: No problem! Always glad to help out, especially when there was valiant effort put into it beforehand.

Comment: Sorry to bother you guys again, but is there any way to have the subTotal and subTotal2 field have a default value of 0.00 so if no items are selected that the subTotal flied will show 0.00 instead of nothing? Thank you again

Comment: I edited my answer again, see the bottom part of it. Pretty simple change.