# force default value on sum field

Tags: jquery

Sorry to bother you guys again, but is there any way to have the subTotal and subTotal2 field have a default value of 0.00 so if no items are selected that the subTotal flied will show 0.00 instead of nothing? Thank you again.

Here is the link to the page with the example:

[more then one jquery calculate on same page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18724357/more-then-one-jquery-calculate-on-same-page)

Answer (score 0):

IF you are using html input just make its value as 0.00 using html code

```
<input value="0.00"/>..
```

If you have values clear the default and append new else it would be 0.00 only..

If not please show your code  too..

Comment: <input value="0.00"/> will not work, the code is in the link I posted